# No network Connection Over Ethernet

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 which is our DHCP server.

On Friday all machines were connected without any issues.

After coming in today there are three machines which cannot connect to the internet when connected directly to the network.

When the machines are set to DHCP they have an error message: `Ethernet has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the Internet.`

When I connect using a static IP it says the Ethernet is connected and does not display any errors, although I am not able to ping our default gateway or any other machine on the network.

Both machines work when connected to our Wi-Fi.

I have changed the network cables to both machines, changed what ports they are connecting into on the switch, deleted certain preference files, flushed the ip / dns, tried about 7-8 things suggested in threads where users had similar issues.

```
    http://superuser.com/questions/1006545/mac-not-connecting-to-internet-with-ethernet-cable
    https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2268121?tstart=0
    http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/fix-self-assigned-ip-addresses-in-os-x/
    http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ethernet-port-keeps-getting-self-assigned-ip-address-and-wont-connect-to-internet.1686426/
```

Currently, most of the machines are having no issues with connecting or getting an IP address, it is only two Mac, and one Linux machine.

When logged into the DHCP Server, event viewer shows no errors in regards to DHCP, when I set a static IP the machines do not appear in the "active" pool.

I tried reserving two IP addresses and setting them statically but it made no difference.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Where / What can I do to troubleshoot this further.

My next thought is to reboot the server but I would like some alternatives before disrupting workflow.

Any help is appreciated and any logs / info needed can be provided.

**Update One:**

After looking through some email logs from the weekend, something appeared to crash, although I can't pin point exactly what as it only affected three machines rather than the whole network, I know this because I have it setup so when a certain program(Deadline Slave 7.2) on a machine loses network connectivity or crashes I get an automated email with the machine info, unfortunately no debugging info in the email.

So all three of those machines suddenly lost their networks yesterday at 3:15.

**IP Config /All - Windows 7 Workstation (Working Machine)**
Note: the 168.168 network does not have a default gateway and is only used to access internal resources.

**Windows IP Configuration**

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WDBL11

    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : domain.com

    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.com

    Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-46-A0-92-49-C9

    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.168.189(Preferred)

    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

    Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.com

    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-46-A0-92-49-CA

    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.156(Preferred)

    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 12, 2016 9:46:44 AM

    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 24, 2016 9:47:42 AM

    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1

    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1

    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1

    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

    Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.com:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.com

    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{FD961D02-7D75-4C0D-ACD0-5656C37B8673}:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    C:\Users\Ryan>
```

**Windows 7 PC Ping - Default Gateway**

**C:\Users\Ryan>ping 192.168.2.1**

```
    Pinging 192.168.2.1 with 32 bytes of data:

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Ping statistics for 192.168.2.1:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

    C:\Users\Ryan>
```

**C:\Users\Ryan>ping domain.com**

```
    Pinging eggbox.ie [192.168.2.1] with 32 bytes of data:

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

    Ping statistics for 192.168.2.1:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

**C:\Users\Ryan>ping 8.8.8.8**

```
    Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:

    Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=57

    Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=57

    Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=57

    Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=57

    Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms

    C:\Users\Ryan>
```

**Linux Workstation on DHCP (Not Working)**

**[root@lw01 ~]# ifconfig**

```
    eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

    RX packets 56656 bytes 4465983 (4.2Mib)

    RW errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

    TX packets 693 bytes 87947 (85.8Kib)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    Device interrupt 20 memory 0xf31000000-f312000000

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 655536

    inet: 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0

    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>

    loop txqueulen 0 (Local Loopback)

    RX packets 2414 bytes 160780 (157.0 Kib)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    virbr0: flags=4099<UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500

    inet: 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255 broadcast 192.168.122.255

    ether 52:54:X0:8X:XC:BX txqueulen 0 (Ethernet)

    RX packers 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

    TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    [root@lw01 ~]#
```

**[root@lw01 ~]#ping 192.168.2.1**

```
    connect: Network is unreachable

    [root@lw01 ~]
```

**Linux Workstation With a Static IP (Not Working)**

**[root@lw01 ~]# ifconfig**

```
    eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

    inet 192.168.2.36 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.94.255

    ether 58:0X:CX:44:XX:7X txqueulen 1000 (Ethernet

    RW errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

    TX packets 867 bytes 119862 (117.0 Kib)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    Device interrupt 20 memory 0xf31000000-f312000000

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 655536

    inet: 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0

    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>

    loop txqueulen 0 (Local Loopback)

    RX packets 2882 bytes 189236 (184.8 Kib)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    virbr0: flags=4099<UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500

    inet: 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255 broadcast 192.168.122.255

    ether 52:54:X0:8X:XC:BX txqueulen 0 (Ethernet)

    RX packers 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0

    TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

    [root@lw01 ~]#ping 192.168.2.1

    PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.94.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

    FROM 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

    FROM 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

    FROM 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

    FROM 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

    --- 162.168.2.1 ping statistics ---

    4 packets transmitted, 0 recieved, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4000ms pipe 4

    [root@lw01 ~]#
```

**Netstat -rn**

```
    Destination     Gateway       Genmask       Flags MSS  Window  Irtt Iface

    0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1   255.255.255.0  UG   0     0       0    0 eno1

    192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U    0     0       0    0 eno1  

    192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U    0     0       0    0 virbr0
```

**arp -a**

```
    DOMAIN (192.168.2.1) at <incomplete> on eno1

    [root@lw01 ~]#
```

**Update Two Somewhat Resolved**

So after Rebooting our Server the issue was still there(My thoughts were, if there was a crash, even if it was brief the server may have been holding onto IP/Mac addresses which is why the workstations couldn't take new ones from the pool, like a hanging PID after a system crash)

Although that was one more thing checked off the list.

We have a 24 port switch so I hooked up the machines that were having issues, this resolved it on the two Mac machines, the Linux workstation still had issues.

The Linux workstation could get an IP address, it could ping the default gateway and access our file servers, but it could not ping locally around the network or access external sites, via Hostname or IP, which is strange since it had no issues connecting to our file Server, I'm chalking that one up to a Host or Configuration file that may have gotten messed up during the crash and will investigate it further.

So, the issue was a dodgy 48 port switch. the reason it was hard to narrow it down was because it was individual ports affected, port 13, 24, 32.
Also, when logging into the switch through a Gui, there were no signs of errors or issues.

Picture of the management console / error log. Last error was reported in April.

http://imgur.com/a/jIqZe

I did move the cables between ports on that switch and they didn't resolve the issue, so I believe there are more ports affected and the switch is on it's last legs.

Before I mark this question as solved, I want to check all the ports so I know which ones are bad and if it is 100% the switch, as looking at the logs / management console on the switch, there appears to be no errors at all on it.

Will post test results / Updates here.

Comment: How experienced are you with wire sniffing tools? It will be interesting to see if the Macs send a HDCP-req and get a NAK, of if either the request or the answer is received.  Other than that the obvious question: Anything in the logs on either the OSX side or the windows server?

Comment: Oh, regarding DNS: When you set a static IP, could you ping the gateway? What was set as DHCP serrver? Could you ping that? (Got a fuzzy notion that the connection might be the problem and DNS just a symptom, so I like to be able to ignore the DNS part).

Comment: @Hennes I have dabbled with wireshark before but nothing too intensive, when pinging any outside address i get "unknown host" when trying to ping the DNS server i get "Destination Host Unreachable", Unfortunately now a Linux workstation is also affected, I will add Ping / Configs above as there is some more information.

Comment: Worth checking:-
Try to connect the macs to each other via ethernet (via patch cables in the switch). This should prove/disprove the ethernet hardware
on Macs have you any settings for Wins under network prefs, and do they check out with the windows domain?
Was the DHCP server recently changed or installed?.

Comment: Could you add these items to your post: 1) Network range, default gateway and name servers from a working system. (e.g. one of the windows systems, do an `ipconfig /all`). 2) Ping the default gateway and DNS server(s) from that working host.  3) Output of the same tests on one of the macs (iirc `ifconfig en0` and `netstat -rn`). Might as well throw in an `arp -a`. 4) Same on the linux host, either via ifconfig or ip (depends on the installation) and `route -show`).

Comment: @Hennes the arp -a one is interesting, cannot get at the Mac machines right now as they're being used, have the windows / lnux output though, thanks for your time!

Comment: 1) Let me see if I understood all correcty: Hosts are multi-homed. Either via two NICs or via multiple IPs on the same NIC.  

2) Internal LAN is 192.168.168.0/24

3) Rest is on 192.168.2.0/24 with gateway 192.168.2.1

If that is correct then the Linux host on DHCP raises my interest. inet: 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255 broadcast 192.168.122.255.  Where does the 122 come from? A rogue DHCP server? Someone playing with VMs and misconfiguring?

Comment: My machine has 2 Nic's as the network is split between two subnets (.168.1 & .2.1) i need access to both, .168 address only routes internally and the .2 address routes internally / outside of the network as well. I'm not sure where the .122.1 address is coming from on the linux machine, on the Mac machine earlier i was getting a 169.254.198.122 address. We have to VMs, One which is running on our DHCP server, but has been running the last year or so without any issues, and our newest one which was configured 2 weeks ago, although that is setup on a secondary server so shouldn't affect our DHCP

Comment: @Hennes removing the "vibr0" interface "sudo ifconfig virbr0 down" doesn't change anything. Still can't ping internally / externally on the linux machine. Going to take a look at the DHCP/DNS on the server again and will post anything I see that might be worthwhile.

Comment: @Hennes Looks like it's a faulty switch, hard to tell since it's only certain ports, need to investigate some more but the two mac machines are back on the network!